# AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication to support both Client Credential and Auth Code Grant flows on same WebAPI endpoint

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

We have several **.Net 6.0 WebAPI** services that we have configured authentication for an **Azure B2C** tenant.

We use **AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication** to configure support for either the **Auth Code Grant flow** or **Client Credential Grant flow**.

Both work great independent of each other but not together.

We would like to be able to support both at the same time, as sometimes we may have a daemon service call through via **Client Credentials grant flow** while other times we have SPA applications accessing the same WebAPIs using the **Auth Code grant flow**.

The following is the configuration for both...

**Authorization Flow Configuration**

```
"AzureADB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://{b2ctenantName}.b2clogin.com/",
    "TenantId": {tenantId},
    "Audience": {webapi clientId}, 
    "ClientId": {webapi clientId},  
    "Authority": "https://{b2ctenantName}.b2clogin.com/nextwaregroupdev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_sign_up_in/v2.0/" 
  },
```

**Client Credential Flow Configuration**

```
"AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "https://{b2ctenantName}.b2clogin.com/",
      "TenantId": {tenantId},
      "Audience": {webapi clientId}, 
      "ClientId": {webapi clientId},  
      "Domain": "https://{b2ctenantName}.onmicrosoft.com",
      "MetadataAddress": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0"
    },
```

When we attempted to include support for both grant flow types as follows ...

**Program.cs**

```
// Enable MS Identity Authentication 
   builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration,"AzureAD");
   builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration,"AzureADB2C");
```

the service throws the following exception..

```
System.InvalidOperationException:Scheme already exists: Bearer
```

I understand the exception but how would I be able to support both flow/grant types using the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication service configuration approach?  OR is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to have one authentication scheme registered with the name *Bearer*. Per default the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` call tries to register the *Bearer* authentication scheme, but you can provide an argument `jwtBearerScheme` with an individual name.

Comment: thank you for your assistance however I tried the following (below) and it is always the last configuration that is the accepted token.  

So in the following example, only the Authorization Token is accepted and if I invert the two lines then only the Client Credential based token is accepted...  

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration,"AzureADB2C","Bearer");
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration,"AzureAD","AzureAD");

Comment: The call registers the authentication scheme as the default, so the last call wins. You need to configure both authenticaiton schemes to be handled. How to do it is explained in this microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes

Comment: `builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        "AzureAD");
    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
});`

Comment: Thank you again however I have tried umpteen combinations as recommended in that link and none of them seem to work for me.  It seems even though I enter both only one but not both will work.  I will be digging deeper and will let you know when I resolve the issue.   Thanks again for your kind assistance! Cheers John